# SQL - Selecting column that contains at least one NULL value?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, presto

How can I filter for where for an output that filters for a certain column having at least one null value?

So for ex. a user that has at least one NULL value in status column?

```
ID    |         Status
B        2017-10-03 08:00:00
B                NULL
G        2017-10-03 08:00:00
G        2017-10-03 08:00:00
G        2017-10-03 08:00:00
B        2017-10-03 08:00:00
D        2017-10-03 08:00:00
D                NULL
D                NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(*) <> count(status);
```

If you want the original rows, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.status is null
             );
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by original rows? wouldn't both queries give me the ID column? Or do you mean all rows and not just grouped by the ID column? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Chris90 . . . The first query gives the `id`s that meet the condition.  The second gives each row where the `id` meetings the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest and fastest approach.

```
select id
from t
where status is null
group by id;
```

Comment: but I do not want all ids that are null, only those that have at least 1 null not all null

Comment: Well that's exactly what you'll get. If there's at least onenull in `status` column for given id it will be in the filter. if you have all status filled for the user id it won't be returned

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
select id
from tablename
where status is null
```

returns all the `id`s that contain at least 1 `status` with `null`.
So use it like this:

```
select * from tablename
where id in (select id from tablename where status is null)
```

If you want just the `id`s:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having sum(status is null) > 0
```